# How do I include a module using a method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, include, rubygems

I have this module that is a part of a gem I'm writing. I currently use it as follows:

```
gem 'foobar' # Gemfile

class Baz < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Foo::Bar
  say
end

module Foo
  module Bar
    module ClassMethods
      def say
        "hello"
      end
    end

    extend ClassMethods
  end
end
```

To make `say` work, I have to `include Foo::Bar` before calling it. Is there anyway to call `say` without first having to include the module? (Have it do the include for me?) I see other gems just magically add methods to classes without using `include`--just a matter of adding the gem and running bundle. How does this happen?

Comment: You have non-workable example: `include ClassMethods`, and `extend Foo::Bar` (and no vice versa) in order to `::say` work after the definition of the class

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid having the `include`?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I'm writing a gem. I want to have the gem's methods available in my class without having to use `include Foo::Bar` in the class. I see many gems that simple add methods with having the `include` first. How do they do this?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I updated my question to clarify it.

Comment: @JumbalayaWanton if you want to avoid the `include Foo::Bar` that is not correct for the include context, you just ass the `::say` metho into the `Class` class as an instance method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `say` method to be general and not specific to objects, make it a class method:

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    def self.say
      "hello"
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can call it directly:

```
class Baz < ActiveRecord::Base
  Foo::Bar.say
end
```

**Edit:** To answer your new question (regarding the gem), you could re-open the `ActiveRecord::Base` class and define the methods there, although doing it with a separate module is the best way (cleaner and semantically correct).

Comment: Is there no way to move the `include Foo::Bar` to the say method itself?

Comment: My intention is to get rid of the `include Foo::Bar` by moving it to the module itself. Is it now possible to have it load from the module?

Comment: I'm working on a gem. What I really want is to be able to use `say` from inside the model, without having to first `include Foo::Bar` in the class.

Comment: This changes a lot then. You should reform your question to get an appropriate question.

Comment: sorry about that. I updated my question. I didn't know it made such a difference.

Comment: Great, thanks. So those `gems` that add methods without having us to include anything are tampering with AR?